# Migrating SQL server 2008 to 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Is there any check list for how to do migration from SQL Server 2008 to SQL server 2016 ?

I am building a new server for the 2016 want to move all the DBs from the old server 2008 to the 2016

any suggestions ?

Comment: The answer there should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you migrate any databases, run 'Assesment' in [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017). It'll point compatibility issues between versions and also show you some best-practice suggestions. Then proceed with actual migration. 
I noticed that one thing that DMA doesn't do, is to raise a warning if a database is running in Sql Server 2005 (or earlier) compatibility mode. Sql 2016 does only support compatibility modes 2008 or higher. So don't trust it blindly as there may be more aspects it ignores.